# Restructuring a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

[image: existing dataframe]

which i want to transpose into the following format:

[image: new dataframe]

Iam not sure whether to use transpose or group_by or pivot_table for achieving the desired format. What should be the best way to do this ?

Comment: This is probably a dupe `df.pivot(columns='Date', index='Account ID')`

Comment: If simply pivot does not work, need `groupby(['Account ID','Date'])['Health'].apply(', '.join).unstack()`